# Need help Identifying the proper globe for an unknown propane lantern

Tags: gear, maintenance

I  "inherited" a two-burner Propane lantern for which I need a globe. Besides a warning label on the section just above the brass cylinder attaching body, it only has a small number (0597) stamped to one side of the single oval match hole in the lower chromed ventilating plate. Three tapered, formed, sheet metal posts attach to that plate and in turn have a formed, sheet metal ring attached near their top, the top flat protruding part of the post splaying outward and fitting into the curved outer rim of the green enameled steel top. The top pulls off to get to the globe or mantles.

The lantern has a push-button piezoelectric ignition button positioned 90* counterclockwise while looking from the base upwards wrt the control knob, and the knob has "Off" and "On", with a thinning red curved band pointing towards the "Off" side.
By my measurements, the globe I need has parallel sides, is ~ 4 3/8"  by about 4 3/4" tall. I found one globe of that diameter and with 4 1/2" height at the Bass Pro site, but that height would only set the top of the glass just above the bottom of the upper ring. The B. Pro lantern that their globe is recommended for has a Coleman lantern type brass nut to hold the top on, so isn't a similar model to mine.

Does anyone have an idea who might have sold this lantern and thus stock the proper globe for it? Searching for globes is difficult as usually just their part number, not dimensions, are listed

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TGO. Would be helpful if you'd provide some pictures!

Comment: Yes, pictures would help us considerably.

Comment: Do you just need the glass globe?

Comment: Can you find a manufacturer's name on it? If not, the  Coleman company may be able to help you, but as said above, pictures are very helpful. Ask them!

Comment: Do you know that it is NOT a coleman?

Comment: Try googling propane lantern on google images.  See if you can find a matching lantern in terms of style of construction.  That may give you a maker.

Comment: Is it [this?](http://m.ebay.com/itm/Coleman-Replacement-Globe-Lantern-Globe-Replacement-No-288-043-0597-/151850877755?_trkparms=aid%253D222007%2526algo%253DSIC.MBE%2526ao%253D1%2526asc%253D20150519202348%2526meid%253Df9e1b9f84e924e7aa0e39344d3913f5a%2526pid%253D100408%2526rk%253D2%2526rkt%253D10%2526sd%253D221356894056&_trksid=p2056116.c100408.m2460) pic [here](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTQ0MFg5MDA=/z/39sAAOSwhcJWIQO0/$_1.JPG)

Answer (score 5):

Edit:  My bad.  Poster is asking for globe -- the glass enclosure on the outside, not the fine thorium oxide ash mantle that breaks so easily.

In passing:  The lantern can be operated without a globe.  I would hesitate to use it in adverse weather.  The mantles are fragile and a strong wind or a raindrop can do them in, but for inside or on calm evenings, they are quite usable.  I have used one for a week on a winter dogsled trip this way.  (Coleman lantern with metal box for it.)

If you are in Canada, Tom Moody seems to have repair part for nearly everything.

Try this:

1. Take your lantern to a local store, and find one with roughly the same size glass as the one you have, with the same number of mantles.  Look it up and buy a set of mantles for it.
2. Use the recommended installation procedure for the mantles.  (Usually tie on, touch a flame to the bottom corner, wait, then light.)
3. Light the lantern.

If only the top part of the mantle glows, you can use a smaller mantle.

If you can't get a consistent bright flame, then you are producing gas too fast for that mantle.  You will need a larger one.

Note:  Mantles are very fragile.  On dog sled trips we would bring a spare set per day, and count ourselves lucky if we didn't use half of them.  In a fixed base they will last for years -- or until the lantern is bumped the wrong way.

---

Alternative.  Take the lantern to various outdoor stores and see if you can identify the maker by similarities in details.  Ask the oldest looking floor help (more likely to have seen it...) for help.

Alternative.  Here the various scout and cadet groups do a course in repairing naphtha powered devices.  They may be able to give you a lead either on the make or the appropriate replacement.

WARNING
There are pressure lanterns designed to run on kerosene.  Operating these on naptha is a potential bomb.  These can usually be identified by a ring shaped depression around the generator designed to allow the use of alcohol to heat the generator.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of pictures; the unit is currently inaccessible.

Comment: Yes, Chris, I just need a replacement globe and would rather not need to make or modify one to fit.

Comment: Ken: as I originally said above, besides a warning label, the lantern only has the one number. I searched through the various models of Coleman lanterns I could find online and saw nothing similar. Most stores around here have a very limited selection and few have employees who know much about anything they are selling, let alone anything ole or different.

Comment: Sherwood:  I don't know why you discuss mantles when I didn't mention them; all I am interested in is finding an original globe. I have built both a few stoves and one lantern from scratch so am fairly knowledgeable about how they work. Just curious; do you know how mantles are made, why they work, or anything about when they were invented?

Comment: Sorry, senior moment.  I conflated globe and mantle in my head.  Should I remove my answer?